# how to dynamically load relations models dynamically in spring rest

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have for example two models Post Comments,
I want my API to send a request `(/posts?include=[comments])` so I need 
dynamically fetch comments eagerly but if send `/posts` I need to just return posts without comments how can I achieve this?

Comment: You could look at using Spring Data Rest https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/ which supports this by means of projections.

Comment: You can match different methods to different cases depending on the existence of query parameters. See `@RequestParam`.